# Can i use cleaning alcohol 90% to remove thermal paste on the cpu?

Tags: cpu, cleaning, thermal-paste

Do i need to buy Arctic Silver cleaner to clean off the thermal paste of the cpu? Can i remove it with a cleaning alcohol or even antistatic cleaner?

Comment: I don't know what "normal" alcohol is, but yes, 90% isopropanol works just fine. If by "normal", you mean "the stuff I guzzle on weekends", then no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular 'rubbing' alcohol, often shown as 71% or less, doesn't remove thermal paste very well, it also contains other items, such as water, which could cause corrosion if not completely cleaned up.

Rubbing alcohol designated 90% or higher can be used.

Like @cody-gray I use isopropanol, mine is 99%.

Comment: 99% isopropanol isn't available where I live, and though I can get 90%, I don't always have it on hand. I've used 70% *many* times and never had a problem. Water is the only concern (no "other items"), but the alcohol ensures that it evaporates quickly enough, especially since you're rubbing it with a cloth to get the thermal grease off.

Comment: @CodyGray in denatured alcohol, also called methylated spirits, they add bad smelling chemicals, dye and other junk. This can still be 96% alcohol, just really foul smelling.

Comment: They don't denature isopropanol. That's only ethanol, to discourage people from drinking it and to get a lower tax rate.

Comment: Apologies, I thought you were commenting on my answer. I get my isopropanol from a medical wholesaler, so getting 99% is pretty easy.

Comment: i wanted to put a new tag "chemistry" but i require to have 300 reputation

Comment: I *was* commenting on your answer. It says "rubbing" alcohol. "Rubbing" is the layperson term for isopropanol.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there isn't a significant amount of water content in the alcohol, you can use it. Although, it is preferable to use the highest percentage that you can get your hands on.